# Как можно найти в матрице bool подматрицы bool?

Tags: search, vector, c++

Задаю подматрицы сам. Например:
`bool one[4][4] =
    {
        {0,1,0,0},
        {1,1,1,0},
        {1,1,0,1},
        {0,1,1,1}
    };` 
    Ищу в большой матрице bool matrix[N][N]; Придумал использовать 
`#include <algorithm>
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    it = std::search (matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), one, one+??)`
    Выдается ошибка. Не подходит оператор. Где косячу?

Изначально надо было в матрице смежности matrix найти 4-вершинные графы. Я решил вбить все 6 видов графов на примере one и искать их в матрице.

Comment: А где Вы тут 

     int one[4][4]

нашли **vector**?

На самом деле у Вас тут просто 16  int, расположенных  последовательно в памяти. 

Точно таких же, как в

     int arr[16]

--

Вам, собственно, что нужно?

Есть матрица `bool matrix[N][N]` и Вы хотите последовательно находить в  ней подматрицы, равные Вашей  `int one[4][4]`?

Comment: Да. Проходить всю matrix и на выходе получить сколько наших one было встречено. вдоль и поперек. Типа перебора. Но перебор будет очень долгий, поэтому ищу быстрее вариант.

Comment: @qrv, у простых массивов нет методов `.begin()` и т.п.

Возможно, Вам помогут [array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/).

Но, чудес не бывает. Будет тот же самый перебор, только еще более мучительный, чем Вы сами можете сделать по памяти.

Comment: @avp
в C++11 есть функции std::begin() и std::end(), которые умеют в сырые массивы.